# Enzyme / Karma / Webpack / Jasmine / React testing not working

Tags: reactjs, webpack, karma-jasmine, enzyme

I've install as per the documentation

npm i --save-dev enzyme

npm i --save-dev react-test-renderer react-dom (currently using React 15.5.4)

And altered my karma.conf file  http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/guides/karma.html
and http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/guides/webpack.html

My tests were running prior to trying to use Enzyme

But I get load errors when I run a .spec.js with these imports

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect, Provider } from 'react-redux'
import ConfigureMockStore  from 'redux-mock-store';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
```

As soon as the  `import { mount } from 'enzyme';` is hit I get (plus a whole lot of other load failures)

```
ERROR in ./~/enzyme/build/react-compat.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'react/addons' in D:\development\poc9-unittests\node_modules\enzyme\build
 @ ./~/enzyme/build/react-compat.js 46:16-39 47:46-69

ERROR in ./~/enzyme/build/react-compat.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'react/lib/ReactContext' in D:\development\poc9-unittests\node_modules\enzyme\build
 @ ./~/enzyme/build/react-compat.js 48:23-56
```

My *karma.conf*  is

```
var webpack = require('karma-webpack');

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({

    singleRun: false,
    watched: true,

    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    browsers: ['Chrome'],

    files: [
      'tests.webpack.js'
    ],

    preprocessors: {
      'tests.webpack.js': [ 'webpack', 'sourcemap' ]
    },

    reporters: [ 'dots' ],

    webpack: {
      devtool: 'inline-source-map',
      module: {
        loaders: [
          {
             test: /\.js$/, 
             loader: 'babel-loader',  
             query: {
                  presets: ['airbnb']
             }
           }
        ]
      }
    },

   externals: {
     'react/addons': true,
     'react/lib/ExecutionEnvironment': true,
      'react/lib/ReactContext': true
    },

    browserNoActivityTimeout: 300000,

    plugins: [
      'karma-webpack',
      'karma-jasmine',
      'karma-sourcemap-loader',
      'karma-chrome-launcher'
    ],

    webpackServer: {
      noInfo: true
    },


  });
};
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Have you installed react-addons-test-utils, which is a dependency for enzyme?

Comment: Yes  "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.4.0"  in both dependencies and devDependencies

Comment: can you setup a github repo, so that we can see what's going on. It's difficult to find the problem just by looking at the config file.

Comment: yes I will, give me 10mins

Comment: Great.. I just realised that I answered another of your questions yesterday. Is it the same repo?

Comment: yes but with more tests, Ill update this repo and let you know

Comment: Why do you have `react-addons-test-utils` in _both_ dependencies and devDependencies? Isn't that weird?

Comment: And I would also remove phantomjs and related deps as they are not used anymore.

Comment: here's the repo   https://github.com/bikerboyroy/Enzyme.. botShowUI.spec.js is where the error occurs

Comment: I am unable to install the dependencies on my machine (probably because I am behind a firewall). But one thing i noticed, which might not be the reason behind your issue, is that you still have query option in your karma.config, which you do not need, as it is coming from babelrc now.

Comment: Do you mean  loaders: [
          {
             test: /\.js$/, 
             loader: 'babel-loader',  
             query: {
                  presets: ['airbnb']
             }
           }
        ]

Comment: yes, but that is not the reason behind your issue. See my answer below. That should fix it (hopefully!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't run your project on my machine, but I remember having a similar issue in the past. Try adding the below to your karma config (inside webpack config), and see if it fixes it:-

```
    webpack: {
      devtool: 'inline-source-map',
      module: {
        loaders: [
          {
             test: /\.js$/, 
             loader: 'babel-loader',  
             query: {
                  presets: ['airbnb']
             }
           }
        ]
      },

      externals: {
      'jsdom': 'window',
      'cheerio': 'window',
      'react/lib/ExecutionEnvironment': true,
      'react/addons': true,
      'react/lib/ReactContext': 'window'
      }
    }
```

Comment: No, same error. I suppose i can start with a 'micro' project and add things in until it breaks

Comment: Can you update your repo to show where you added it?

Comment: Sorry, I meant could you update the repo with the change of adding the 'externals' in karma config.

Comment: ok, I've updated the karma conf. I'm off home now but back online in an hour or so

Comment: You have specified externals in the wrong place. They should be inside the webpack config. I have updated my answer with the correction.